# The bends do not work. What's the problem?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node at (1,2) {Β};
        \node at (-5,2) {Α};

        \draw [thick] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm] node [below = 2.3cm] {Σύνολο Άφιξης};;
        \draw [thick] (-4,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm] node [below = 2.3cm] {Πεδίο Ορισμού};
        
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (p1) at (-3.9,1) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (p2) at (-3.5,-0.3) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (p3) at (-4,-1.2) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (p4) at (-4.4,0.2) {};

        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a1) at (0.3,1) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a2) at (0.5,0) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a3) at (-0.2,-1.2) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a4) at (-0.4,-0.3) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a5) at (-0.4,0.8) {};
        \node[circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black] (a6) at (0.3,-0.8) {};
        
        \draw [thick, ->, out=135] (p1) -- (a1);
        \draw [thick, ->, bend right = 90] (p3) -- (a5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\draw [bend right=90] (p3) -- (a5);` has to be `\draw (p3) to[bend right=90] (a5);`

Comment: Also “does not work” and no further explanation in the question is hardly a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 7):

As noted @Henri Menke, bending had to be between coordinates in form, for example:

```
\draw[<arrows options>] (a) to [bending left] (b);
```

where `a` and `b` are start and end coordinates of arrow respectively. This way is used in MWE below.

Another way is use of an `edge` which style can be defined in `tikzpicture` options or in `\tikzset{...}` and than used for example as:

```
\path (a) edge [bend left] (b)
      (c) edge [bend right] (c);
```

where edge style is defined for example by:

```
every edge/.stale = {draw, ->, semithick}
```

Considering the first option and defining common style for dots, image code is much shorter:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1.5pt}
                        ]
\node at (1,2)  {Β};
\node at (-5,2) {Α};
% elipses
\draw [thick] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm] node [below = 2.3cm] {Σύνολο Άφιξης};;
\draw [thick] (-4,0) ellipse [x radius=1cm, y radius=2cm] node [below = 2.3cm] {Πεδίο Ορισμού};
% dots
    \begin{scope}[nodes=dot]
\node (p1) at (-3.9,1) {};
\node (p2) at (-3.5,-0.3) {};
\node (p3) at (-4,-1.2) {};
\node (p4) at (-4.4,0.2) {};

\node (a1) at (0.3,1) {};
\node (a2) at (0.5,0) {};
\node (a3) at (-0.2,-1.2) {};
\node (a4) at (-0.4,-0.3) {};
\node (a5) at (-0.4,0.8) {};
\node (a6) at (0.3,-0.8) {};
    \end{scope}
% arrows
\draw [thick, ->] (p1) to [bend  left] (a1);
\draw [thick, ->] (p3) to [bend right] (a5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think saying bending options had to be given to `to` (or `edge`) path command is better.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, you are right. In MWE is used `to`. Probably I didn't sufficient emphasize this in explanation. I will try to did this in edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is not a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), in particular, it is not compliable (due to the lack of some language package. Helpers don't want to care about your language. You should get rid of it when asking for help). I did remove some Russian characters from your code, also retype annoying characters `A` and `B`.

Second, `bend left`, `bend right`, `out=`, `in =`, etc. work with the `to` operation (see **Section 74.3
Curves** in [pgfmanual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)). So you can just replace `--` by `to`, that is replace

```
\draw [thick, ->, bend right = 90] (p3) -- (a5);
```

by

```
\draw [thick, ->, bend right = 90] (p3) to (a5);
```

to make it works as expected.

Third, I clean your code by using a style `dot`, loop `\foreach`, and `scope`; also `+` operation, old but shorter syntax `ellipse`; the names `a\i`, `b\i`. Several tiny things in a tiny piece of code ^^

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}]
\draw[thick] 
(0,0)  ellipse(1 and 2) +(1.2,2) node (B) {$B$}
(-4,0) ellipse(1 and 2) +(-1.2,2) node (A) {$A$};

\foreach \point [count =\i from 1] in {(-3.9,1), (-3.5,-0.3), (-4,-1.2), (-4.4,0.2)}    
\node[dot] (a\i) at \point {};

\foreach \point [count =\i from 1] in {(0.3,1), (0.5,0), (-0.2,-1.2), (-0.4,-0.3), (-0.4,0.8), (0.3,-0.8)}  
\node[dot] (b\i) at \point {};

\begin{scope}[-stealth,magenta]
\draw (a1) -- (b1);
\draw[bend right = 30] (a3) to (b4);
\draw[bend left]       (a2) to (b2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```